# 変数の値が増えたか減ったかの判定方法

Tags: javascript, swift, php, java, vba

Swiftで実装したいのですがロジックが応用できればどんな言語でも構いません。とある変数の値（数字）が動的に変わるのですが、その変数の値が増えたのか減ったのかで処理を分岐させたいと思っています。コードは下記のような感じです。

```
if(変数の値が増えた){

print("変数の値が増えた！")

}esle if(いや、変数の値が減った){

print("変数の値が減った！")

}
```

実装の方法が思いつきません。アドバイスいただければ幸いです

Comment: 古い値を何らかの変数に保持しておき、それを現在の値と比較するだけでは？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/79850

Answer (score 0):

変更前の値と変更後の値を配列にとって配列の最初と最後を比較することで解決しました

Comment: マルチポスト先の https://teratail.com/questions/79850 で回答を得て、解決済。